# How to get git to pull changes for all branches

Tags: git, github

I'm working with a git repo that has an empty master and multiple branches. When I do a git pull, it only seems to pull stuff down for the master but does not apply for the branches.

I find myself having to do `git checkout branch; git pull` for each branch before I can push. Is there a command or switch I can use that does

*Pull and apply changes to all branches and master?*

Comment: When you pull, it fetches all the branches into their local copies (the stuff under remotes/origin/...), so you don't actually need to run 'git pull' every time, just change branch and do git merge origin/branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Answer (score 7):

I think there is no available command or switch because of what `git pull` does - it fetches changes from remote (like `git fetch`) and them merges changes to your current branch (`git merge origin/master` or whatever your current branch tracks). Problem is not first part (actually `git fetch` fetches changes for all remote branches) but merge - what should be done when you have merge conflicts? You can only merge on working copy, not on git objects. And when you start merging, then you need to abort it or resolve all conflicts and create merge commit.

Comment: +1. It would be trivial to write a script to do it, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem isn't with `git pull` it's with `git push`.  Try setting up git to only push to the branch the current branch is tracking (if applicable):

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

In the meantime, you *are* able to push whenever you want, but you'll get rejection notices for branches that wouldn't fast-forward on push.  Those are quite often branches you aren't working on so don't much care about.

The above config will give you a bit more sensible behavior when you don't specify what to push.

Comment: Nice!  I wasn't aware of the push.default configuration option.  The manual page for git-push offers an alternate but similar solution: git config remote.origin.push HEAD