# git pull remote multiple branches at once?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “git pull --all” update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

`git fetch origin` fetches information about all branches (not just the checked-out branch) from the given remote, but `git pull origin` only merges changes for the currently-checked-out branch. Is there a simple command to pull changes (that are fast-forward only) for all tracked branches from that remote?

Currently I have to go:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin
git checkout branch1
git pull origin
git checkout branch2
git pull origin
```

And since the remote in question is an SSH connection, I have to give my SSH password three times (yes, I know I could set up SSH keys to auto-login...), and I'd rather just enter it once.

Comment: True; thanks for identifying. Voting to close.