# Moving to gitolite missing some branches

Tags: git, gitolite

I've created a new empty gitolite repo into which I want to push a snapshot (on my workstation) of my original git repo.  I followed the instructions to do `git push --all` followed by `git push --tags`.  This seemed to work great, but I find that some branch references didn't get pushed.  Running `git show-ref` on my workstation shows a number of refs of the sort `refs/remotes/origin/branchXyz`, but doing `git show-ref` directly on the gitolite repo doesn't show this branch name at all (I expected to see it appear as `refs/heads/branchXyz`.  How can I push the remaining branches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your local repo was itself a clone (of '`origin`', another non-gitolite repo), it didn't have all the branches *locally*, only references to remotes ('`origin`') branches.

You should [first pull all branches or track them all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312552/6309):

```
$ git remote update  
$ git pull --all

# or:

remote=origin ; for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | awk '{gsub(/[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do git branch --set-upstream $brname  $remote/$brname ; done
```

(The last command is [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309))

(Both options are also detailed in "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)", and in "[Can “`git pull --all`” update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)" or "[How do I clone all remote branches with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git)")

Then `push --all` to your new (gitolite) [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) repo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also thanks for all the useful links.  I was under the impression that `git fetch` pulled the history of the whole repository and that, therefore, I would have all of the remote branches as well.  If I understand correctly, this is wrong; `git fetch` will only pull the history for the remote branches that are tracked.  `git clone` is insufficient, I would also need to do a `git pull --all` before having any hope of being able to do a `git push --all`.  Is that right?

Comment: @torngat no, `git fetch` pull all branches too (they are in `remotes/origin/heads`), you are just not tracking them, and `git push --all` pushes only tracked branches (the ones in `refs/heads/`). Look at `git branch -a` after a `git fetch`

Comment: @tornga > `git fetch` pull all branches too: yes, but not tracked by local branches. Hence your issue after pushing to gitolite.

Comment: @VonC `git remote update` and `git pull -all` had no visible effect (`git branch`) still doesn't report any other local branch than master.  However, the other command you suggested did seem to have an effect.  But I'm puzzled by the messages.  Here's an example:

`Branch origin/BR_EM_141 set up to track local branch master.`

Does this mean that I have a local branch named BR_EM_141 that is tracking master?  I want it to track remote BR_EM_141.

Comment: @torngat: that means the second command isn't exactly working as intended. I have replaced in my own (answer edited), with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309 which explains it.