# Pushing git submodules to a downstream remote

Tags: git

I know the summary isn't too informative so I'll try and explain the problem in detail as best I can. We're developing code that is required to interface with portions of a code base that a contractor is responsible for. So we want to have access to the contractor's code but we can't all have direct access to their company servers.

What we've done is we've set up an onsite contractor with an account on our code server. We've created a bare git repo on our code server for the contractor's code and we've setup the onsite contractor's local repository to have our code server as a downstream remote.

So his local repo is acting as a middle man for us. The problem is that the contractor's code contains sub modules and these aren't automagically pulled down when we clone the repo from our code server. And when we try to do

```
$git submodule update
```

on our local machines, its trying to grab the submodules from the contractor's servers.

Is there a smart way to allow submodules to also be pushed to a second remote so that we can use them locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bare repo on your code server for each of those submodules. Now the contractor needs to add these repos as remotes to his submodules (giving all those remotes the same name, e.g. `external` . After pushing the main repo to your server, he then runs `git submodule for-each 'push external HEAD:tempbranch'` in the main repo. This will push all the submodules to your server.

Finally you need to have a look at your `.git/config` – there you will see how to make the submodule use your own server instead of the client’s. Then run `git submodule update`.

**Note**: This will only work as long as the submodules only have one branch. If that’s not the case, the calls `push external HEAD:tempbranch` will override the other branch head. You will first need to pull all the branches in all the submodules. To achieve this you could use [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) with `git submodule for-each up` or have a look here: [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches) for alternate solutions. Next you need to run `git submodule for-each push --all`.

Comment: I had the opportunity to give this a go yesterday and it all worked out. Thanks for your help.