# Does git pull copy all the branchs or just the master?

Tags: git, github

I would like to know if git pull will update all my branches or just the master branch?

Or

Does it just pull the current branch I am working in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just updates the currently checked out branch.

More specific: it will `fetch` all the branches (= update the `origin/*` branches), and then merge the matching remote branch into the currently checked out branch. So if you’re in `master`, `git pull` is equivalent to:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

If you want to pull all the branches, have a look at this question: [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Comment: so then it does not refresh my full repo?

Comment: no.  you need to use `git fetch` directly for that, and you'd still have to update your local branches manually

Comment: so I need to do a git fetch for each branch and then a merge? is it anything like a clone that will get them all

Comment: `git fetch` will get all your branches. you will still need to merge the remote branches into your local ones as needed

Comment: This answer is correct, but misleading. `git pull` combines `git fetch` _for_ _all_ _branches_ with `git merge` (or `git rebase`, if you have it configured that way) in the currently checked out branch. So if you have master checked out, `git pull` will merge the newly fetched origin/master into master. It will update all the other origin/* branches, after which you may manually merge in those changes if necessary.

Comment: `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the same arguments—so if you're using the pretty common `git pull origin master`, that's what you'll fetch

Answer (score 0):

try`git pull --help`

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.