# Pulling/Tracking changes on live Wordpress site with Git

Tags: php, wordpress, git

I've just completed a Wordpress site revamp for a client and I've implemented using git to work locally then deploy to a dev/testing server and then deploy to a live/production server using Beanstalk.

Since I used Wordpress as a CMS, I've allowed the client access to update the site.

But if I need to make changes to the template files, how do I go about tracking the updated files from the live site and then pull them down to my local branch?

Like I said, I'm using Beanstalk, so I'm not sure if I have to /need to go through that or if I can SSH and just pull or fetch the files from there via the command line.

I've search through some other questions and I read about git-up:
[Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

But I'm not sure if I need to implement that before I pushed it out to production or what.

Answer (score 1):

To use git properly, your client should clone the repository, commit the changes, and push back to your repository.  Thus, changes are tracked by git.  [Here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) is a great tutorial to get moving quickly with git.

As for using `beanstalk`, if it works for you great, but if you know the command line then you are less dependent and restricted to always have to have access to beanstalk.

EDIT:
The link you provided is complicated for a beginner in git.  I suggest you spend sometime on tutorials first.

Hopefully my briefness and the link will help you.

Comment: Ok, got. Hmmmmm.
Well, that kinda shoots it out of the water for the most part. I think I need to re-work my thinking about tracking what should be tracked. More than anything, I technically don't need the entire Wordpress site, just the template files since that's what I'm going to edit.

Comment: Yes, for this particular application, I think git is overkill.  You could look into some `source control` software, but really, I suggest letting client make changes and you use software like [Diff Doc](http://www.softinterface.com/md/document-comparison-software.htm).  Any kind of `document comparison` tool should work for you.