# Git pull for all branches in local repository

Tags: git, git-pull

Seemingly `git pull` does fetch and merge only for the current branch, is there an easy way to `pull` for all branches in local repo?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git-up`](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) for this. It will automate the process of fetching and rebasing all locally-tracked remote branches. You don't have to type multiple commands again and again. You can achieve this in a single command.

**Installation:**

```
gem install git-up
```

**Usage:**

```
git up
```

This command will then fetch and rebase all the locally-tracked remote branches automatically.

[image: gitup]

For more configuration options with git-up, check out this [link](http://aanandprasad.com/git-up/#CONFIGURATION).