# Fetch all git files

Tags: git

I currently use `git clone` to get my files back in my local.
My problem is when i run the command only the master files was download but the other branch was not download, so I'm thinking you guys could help me what should i do to get all the files in my repository including all the created files in a certain branch.

I'm new to git that's why i don't know the exact process to do this

I have look at this [How to fetch all git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches) but it does not help me..

Comment: Try looking into `git-up`:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say I have a repository with three branches

```
1 - master
2 - feature1
3 - feature2
```

You can then perform a `git clone` which will clone the entirety of the repo onto your local machine and will default you to the master branch; however, if you want to instead see the code on one of the feature branches, you will need to "checkout" that code on your local machine. You have at least three ways of things panning out here:

```
git checkout master
```

Git will tell you that you are already on the master branch

```
git checkout nonExistantBranch
```

Git will tell you that the requested branch does not exist

```
git checkout feature1
```

Git will successfully "checkout" the code. So, when you open any of the files on your local machine, they will reflect the code found on that specific branch only. This is the option that you want.

If you are getting an error saying the branch doesn't exist, but you think it does, perform a  `git branch -v` which will show all the branches in the current repository.

There is a another option

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

This will tell git to switch to "newBranch" and if it doesn't exist, create it, using the code that is currently found on the branch you currently have checked out.

Comment: sir if i run that checkout it will create another branch right?

Comment: It will not. It will switch to it if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will say something like "branch not found".

Comment: sir could you update your answer starting from git clone down to getting the files in other branch? because when i run the checkout command error came up. It would be a great answer. :)

Comment: @jameshwartlopez when you run `git clone` it gets the entire repo (including branches). A link to the documentation: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 0):

You did download the content of all branches, but git checked-out only the master branch. To see other branches, run `git branch --all` (or `git branch -a` for short). A branch named `foo` on the remote repository will be tracked as `remotes/origin/foo` in your repository. At the time of cloning, your `remotes/origin/foo` will be exactly identical to the remote's `foo`. If the remote `foo` gets updated later, you can update your remote-tracking with `git fetch`.

As the other answer noted, you can checkout `remotes/origin/foo` with `git checkout foo`, which is a shortcut for `git checkout -b foo --track remotes/origin/foo`.