# Does a git pull update all tracked branches?

Tags: git

Say I'm locally tracking 3 remote branches, `master`, `branch1`, `branch2`.

If I'm currently on the `master` branch, will a `git pull` `fetch` and `merge` changes on each of the branches?

I guess I could build out an experiment, too...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The short answer is "no"—or maybe even "no and yes", if one reads only the title of your question—but this is somewhat misleading.

The pull command allows options, and many of these have interesting (and confusing and potentially very un-nice) effects.

> **Sidebar:**  Make sure you correctly understand the [differences between what the Git documentation calls remote branches, remote-tracking branches and tracking branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) to take full advantage of the following explanations.  Note that these are terms that Git (and git-scm.com) use.  Long after I wrote this answer originally, I find these terms just confuse people—including me!—and these days, I prefer my own terminology.  Instead of *remote branch*, I like to say *branch name as seen on the other (remote) Git repository;* instead of *remote-tracking branch name* (e.g., `origin/master`), I call this a *remote-tracking name;* and instead of *tracking branch*, I use the phrase *branch name with an upstream set*.  But be prepared for Git documentation to use their terminology.

Remember, `git pull` is basically shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  The `pull` command passes most of its arguments right through to the `fetch` step.  For instance, if you `git fetch origin br`, the `fetch` step gets the name of the remote (`origin`) and `br` as a "refspec".  In versions of Git predating 1.8.4, this prevented `git fetch` from updating *any* of your remote-tracking branches, but since 1.8.4, explicitly fetching branch *`br`* also updates your `origin/br` (assuming the remote in question is named `origin`).

If you don't pass extra arguments, `git fetch` will *fetch* the default set of refspecs for the remote, which is normally<sup>2</sup> "all branches".  This means that either `git fetch` (assuming `origin`) or `git fetch origin` will update all your remote-tracking branches for `origin`, provided you are running a reasonably modern (1.8.4 or later) Git.  (In sufficiently old versions of Git I think the `pull` command gets more restrictive during the fetch step.)

But, having potentially fetched and updated all the `origin/*` remote-tracking branches, the `pull` code moves on to the `git merge` step.  For this part, Git cares mightily about which branch you're on now, and which "remote branch"<sup>3</sup> it merges with.  If, as in your example, you're currently on `master` and it merges with `origin`'s `master`, Git will run the `git merge` step using whatever new stuff it brought in that went under `origin/master` (note the slash here).

#### Technical nitty details: the "refspec"

I used the word "refspec" above several times, without ever defining it.

The "refspec" is, at its second-simplest, just a pair of branch names, like `master:master`, `develop:develop`, and the like.

The pair usually, but not always, has the same two branch names on both sides of the colon `:` between them.  One of these is *your* name—your branch, in your repository—and the other is *their* name, that is, the name *they* use for *their* branch in *their* repository.

Usually you see this two-names form when pushing: `git push origin master:master` for instance.  This means "pack up what I have in my master, call up the remote named `origin` over the Internet-phone, send him the package, and ask him if he'll make this his `master` branch."  You can also use, on the left, a commit ID or the word `HEAD`: `git push origin HEAD:master` means "take whatever commit I'm on now, and ask the remote `origin` to make that his `master`".

When doing a `git fetch` the sides get reversed, and normally you also add `origin/` (or the name of your remote) in front of the name you want on your side.  That is, you get *his* `master`, but call it `origin/master` in *your* repository.  So you `git fetch origin master:origin/master`, and so on.<sup>4</sup>  If you did `git fetch origin master:master` you would (potentially) wipe out work you did on your own master.<sup>5</sup>

There's one other odd thing with `fetch` vs `pull`.  I said this is the "second simplest" form of a refspec.  The simplest is just an unadorned name like `master`.  The *meaning* of this depends on which you're doing: for `fetch`, it means "bring over his `master`, but don't necessarily give it *any* name in my local repository, just save the hash ID."  For `push`, it means "give him my `master` and ask him to call it `master`".

Again, in old versions of git, if you asked `git fetch` to bring over their master (and maybe others), without giving `fetch` a local name to use for it, it would *only* save the ID (and their name for the branch) in Git's `FETCH_HEAD` file.  In newer (1.8.4 and later) versions of Git, git uses the `fetch =` configuration entry to figure out what remote-tracking branch(es) to update.

#### The ugly: `git pull origin master branch` (don't do it)

If you tell `git fetch` to bring over several branches, that works fine (with Git 1.8.4 or later anyway).  But if you tell `git pull` to take several branches, it behaves badly.

The `fetch` step works fine.  Things go wrong at the `merge` step.

The `pull` code asks `git merge` to merge multiple branches into your current branch.  Git calls this an "octopus merge".  Unless you're into advanced branching, you almost certainly don't want that.  So don't do it.

#### Bottom line

I advise doing one `git fetch`, which will by default bring over all, then doing individual `git merge` or `git rebase` ops.  You'll be able to see what you're doing.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or `git rebase`, if so configured or directed.  Rebasing is usually better than merging, though it always depends on details.  My advice here is to use `git fetch` first, then do your own `git rebase` or `git merge` as a separate step, at least while you're new to Git.  I think it's actually *less* confusing this way, though admittedly you have to type in two commands instead of just one.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, it's whatever is in the `fetch =` lines in the configuration for that remote.  The normal line for remote `origin` reads `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, which is how git knows to rename origin's branches to your `origin/whatever` branches.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, Git just uses a raw hash ID, saved in a file named `FETCH_HEAD`.  The term *remote branch* here in quotes is the standard Git term: the branch name as seen on the repository that is feeding commits to your Git through your `git fetch` command.

<sup>4</sup>I'm leaving out one more thing, which is the leading `+` sign: when fetching "their master", you usually want to forget any previous idea you had about "their master", so the `fetch =` line has that leading plus sign.  This turns on the "force" flag, i.e., update even if it's not a fast-forward operation.  The `fetch =` line also spells everything out in full to avoid problems if you accidentally name a local branch `origin/something`, and uses the `*` character to match multiple branch names.

<sup>5</sup>If you *do* clobber your own work, you can almost always get it back.  Git really tries to hang on to everything for at least 30 days.  We'll leave "how to get it back" to other SO entries though.

Comment: From the formulation of the question I am not sure the OP originally was aware of the differences between a remote branch, a remote-tracking branch and a tracking-branch. Therefore, I'll add a link to the documentation explaining these terms. Apart from that, I feel like (currently) 21 points don't do justice for such a holistic and understandable answer.

Comment: @Johnson: I approved your edit but went back and added a bit more, as I've revised how I write some of these things over the last 5 years. (Also `git pull` is no longer a script, and Git 2.29 has some initial support for using SHA-256 instead of SHA-1.)

Comment: I also realized that the terminology (even in the git documentation) changed a bit over time. However, I prefer sticking closely to terminology coined by "official" resources. I agree that the documentation still has some confusing/ambiguous parts (at least in my understanding). I raised a pull request hopefully improving upon that.

Comment: @S.B: I meant it the way it's written. It's `git fetch` that updates, or fails to update, remote-tracking names. The `git pull` command runs `git fetch`, so there are two steps to `git pull`: (1) `git fetch`, then (2) a second Git command (of your choice). It's the `git fetch` step *of* `git pull` that we're concerned with, here. If you `git pull origin br`, you `git fetch origin br`. Perhaps there's a clearer way to put this.

Comment: Just a small question: Am I right with this sentence? : `git pull` without arguments, does the `git fetch <origin>` step, which updates all the remote-tracking-brances and then does `git merge FETCH_HEAD`?

Comment: More or less, yes. The `git merge` (or `git rebase`) command doesn't directly use `FETCH_HEAD` itself though, but rather the commit hash ID(s) extracted *from* `FETCH_HEAD`, or, in the latest Git version (with it all one big C program now) the hash IDs that the fetch step wrote to `FETCH_HEAD` (it already knows those since the same program wrote them, so it doesn't have to retrieve them again).

Answer (score 13):

No.  `git-pull` will only ever incorporate changes [to your local branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).  If you want the updates for each other branch, you'll have to check them out and `pull` down their updates individually.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `git pull --all` to pull all the tracked remote branches or `git fetch --all` to fetch them and decide later how to proceed. Be aware that *pull* usually automatically merges any change and it is seldom what you want.

Comment: That will just fetch from all remotes, not merge with local branches.

Answer (score -1):

No, pull only merge changes to current local branch.

Based on that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59793998/14557599 I've added a function to `/etc/bash.bashrc` to do that:

```
git_pull() {
    echo - pulling all tracked local branches from "origin" remote
    orig_branch=$(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/[ *]*//") # getting name of current branch via asterisk
    git fetch | return 1
    for branch in $(git branch | sed "s/[ *]*//") ; do # remove spaces and asterisk
        git checkout $branch && git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD
    done
    echo - checking out to branch where function was called from 
    git checkout $orig_branch
}; export -f git_pull
```