# What's the difference between putting Origin and not putting in using Git?

Tags: git, git-pull

hope you're doing well!

Actually, I want to know the difference between putting **Origin** using **Git** in a command and not putting it.

for instance :

`git pull origin master` *is it the same as* `git pull master` *and* `git pull`? *and why*?

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Not sure of what `git pull master` does... `pull` is not usually used for local actions. Use `merge` instead. Additionnaly, you can use `remotes/origin/branch_name`, which points to the local reference you have for the branch _branch_name_, but then the `HEAD` of that branch can at a different state than the one on the remote `origin`. Git is full of tricks !

Comment: Another interesting post could help too, for comprehension : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402589/does-a-git-pull-update-all-tracked-branches

Comment: Okay, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull origin master` is telling git to pull from the `master` branch of the remote called `origin`.

Doing just `git pull` will pull in changes from all the branches of the default remote i.e. `origin`. `git pull` is equivalent to `git pull origin` by default.

When using `git pull` from any checked out branch, you first need to tell git what **remote** and which **branch** you mean to pull from (again, by default the remote is `origin`).

In git's terminology it is called setting up the remote tracking branch for your locally checked out branch and you do so by running below command,

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`

Considering your currently checked out branch is `master`, then the above command tells git to **tie the master branch of local with the master branch of remote**.

Once you have set up your local master(or any other branch) branch to track the remote branch `master` from `origin`, you can then perform just `git pull` and git would be smart enough to understand that it has to fetch in changes from `origin/master` and merge to `master` of local.

You can also combine the task of setting up remote tracking branch and pulling in changes from the tracking branch into one single command,

`git pull --set-upstream origin master`

OR

`git pull -u origin master`

You can always replace `origin` with any other remote of your interest, likewise `master` with any other branch. `Origin` is just the git's way of providing default name for remote which usually points to the original repo that you cloned from.

You can check the configured remotes by,

`git remote -v`

You also mentioned about `git pull master`. This is not a valid command.
The general syntax of a git pull command is : [`git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`origin` is the remote you pull from. `master` is the branch.

If you omit the remote and the branch, git uses a default. You can inspect the defaults for each branch with `git branch -avv`.

`git pull master` is not a valid command unless `master` is a remote.

Comment: Actually, I changed the branch main to master