# NodeGit - Merge remote branch into local branch without checking out

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I have two branches "master" and "master.min".

Switching from "master.min" to "master" takes lot of time. I need to merge the changes from origin/master to master without checking out "master".

I am using

http://www.nodegit.org/

A problem similar to

[Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)