# How to update the repository with all new branches

Tags: git

How can I update the local repository with all new branches?

Example:

**Remote**: **master**, **develop**, **feature1**, **feature2**(new branch) and **feature3**(new branch) branches.

**Local**: **master**, **develop** and **feature1** branches.

> **What I need**:
>
> Update my local and "download" all the branches

.

Comment: If you really want to do this in one operation you will need an extension such as `git up`, which does a `git fetch` and then merges the tracking branches into your local branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with what Git ships out of the box, then you will have to checkout each local branch and do a `git pull origin branch_name` to update the branch:

```
git fetch origin         # "downloads" feature2 and feature3

git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout feature1
git pull origin feature1
```

If you install `git up`, then you can do this with a single command:

```
git up
```

Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches) for more information.

Comment: Awesome, I'll see this git up. Thanks!!

Comment: It might be worth providing a link for "git up": a google search reveals at least two Git-related projects with that name, neither of which are spelled exactly how you've spelled it. E.g. the unmaintained [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up), or [GitUp](http://gitup.co/) which appears to be a Mac only GUI client.

Answer (score 0):

For seeing all branches(local as well as remote), You can use

```
git branch -a
```

This command shows all branches(differentiate local and remote branches
with different color). 
After that use git fetch command for fetching any remote branch on local

```
git fetch origin remote_branch_name:local_branch_name
```

You can change branch name at the time of fetching(just give
the name what you want to local branch name).
You can also able to fetch all remote branches at a time

```
git fetch --all
```

For more detail how fetch command works, 
please go through [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)