# > You asked to pull from the remote '--prune'

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm getting this error when using one of my aliases `bdone`

> You asked to pull from the remote '--prune', but did not specify a
>   branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your
>   current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

This is the alias I use

```
alias.bclean !f() { git branch --merged ${1-master} | grep -v  ${1-master}$ | xargs git branch -d; }; f
alias.bdone !f() { git checkout ${1-master} && git up && git bclean ${1-master}; }; f
```

I have nothing to commit `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: `git up` is not a standard command; what package/alias are you using for `git up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You asked to pull from the remote '`--prune`', but did not specify a branch

That means the remote name was empty, and the next command-line parameter (here `--prune`) was interpreted (wrongly) as the remote name.

This may be a bug in [git-up.rb](https://github.com/aanand/git-up/blob/master/lib/git-up.rb#L6-L14), but the [project git up](http://aanandprasad.com/git-up/) is not maintained anymore. It says:

> As of Git 2.9, `git pull --rebase --autostash` does basically the same thing.

So, if you have [git 2.9 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), do:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then you can replace `git up` by a simple classic `git pull`.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.10 and applied the config commands you suggested. that fixed the problem.