# Is there a way to clone a git repository including its remote repositories?

Tags: git, git-svn, git-clone, git-remote

Is there a way to use some **git clone / fetch** mechanism to keep the repo in my clone up to date including all **refs/remotes/ from the remote**?

This has nothing to do with `git fetch --all`, `git pull --all` or `git svn`. It's just about copying the remotes of a remote to a clone.

A command like this would be great:

```
git clone --include-remote-remotes git@linuxmachine:TheGitSvnClone
```

And then periodically

```
git fetch --update-remote-remotes origin
```

**Some Details:**

The remote has its own remote named *svn* which contains some branches:

- refs/heads/master
- refs/remotes/svn/trunk
- refs/remotes/svn/branch1
- refs/remotes/svn/branch2

As a result of the clone I'd expect a normal git repository including a working copy (checked out files) and the following refs:

- refs/heads/master
- (refs/remotes/origin/master)
- refs/remotes/svn/trunk
- refs/remotes/svn/branch1
- refs/remotes/svn/branch2

I can't use `git clone --mirror` because that creates a bare repository.

**Why so complicated?**

Our company is currently using svn. Meanwhile I'm preparing the migration from svn to git.

Unfortunately `git svn fetch` takes forever on my windows machine so I'm using a linux machine that does the `git svn fetch` periodically and then I copy the resulting git repo using FileZilla.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Comment: Nope. This doesn't have anything to do with pulling / fetching from different remotes.

Comment: What i don't understand is why you don't switch completely to git? Why do you make such things with fetch and copy?

Comment: I had to do just this about a year ago, and I blogged about it.  Could help. https://123code.co.uk/view/Resources/migrating-a-subversion-repository-to-git

Comment: We are also bound to SVN at work currently. So until we switch to Git I'm also using `git-svn` to at least use git as frontend. I've setup a Windows task that runs every 15 minutes that does `git svn fetch` as long as I'm connected to work network. So I never miss more than 15 minutes which doesn't need much time and I can always do a rebase to bring in the latest changes into my local working branches. Works perfectly for me, maybe it is also the way to go for you.

Comment: The repo is quite big, around 2000 branches, 200000 commits, 60000 files. `git svn fetch` takes around 5 to 20 minutes per commit on a windows machine and around 20 seconds on the linux VM in our data center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After cloning the repository normally, instruct Git to fetch the remote refs:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/svn/*:refs/remotes/svn/*'
```

Subsequent `git fetch` calls will download the `svn` refs.

Comment: Is there a way to download the refs once, as opposed to every time the remote is fetch-ed?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Sure, just unset the option after you are done: `git config --unset remote.origin.fetch 'refs/remotes/svn/'`. This is safe because the destination in the answer was given as `refs/remotes/svn/*`, which is outside the namespace of `origin` (that would be `refs/remotes/origin`), so `git fetch --prune origin` does not delete the one-time-fetched refs.

Comment: This makes sense, but it does not solve what I'm asking for. I don't want to unset the remote. I might post my own question. Thanks for replying.