# git: how to pull ALL branched from remote repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository that has some branches that I don't have on my local repository. I want to import ALL branches from the remote repository to my local one. I tried to use "git pull" or "git fetch" and I stayed with the same branches I had before on my local repo. Do you know what can help me?

Comment: If you do `git branch -a`, do you see the other branches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull origin <remote-branch-name>
```

ensure to resolve conflicts, if any, then perform merging by commiting

```
git commit -m "pulled from brach-name"
```

Comment: But what if I have 1000 branches in remote repo and I want to bring them all in one command ?

Comment: u can also merge online by selecting the relevant branches into master. i believe that can help.