# Git pull vs git pull --all

Tags: git-pull, git-fetch

In the Git manual it states that the --all option is for the fetch part. I'm confused because I thought git fetch would update the whole local copy of the remote repository by default, so I don't see the need to define --all. And the main question, is git pull the same as git pull --all? if not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--all fetches all refs from all remotes, instead of just the needed one. Then merges the appropriate single branch.

Answer (score 0):

This link question asked in stack overflow earlier would resolve your issue - 
[Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)