# git pull returns "Already up-to-date" but branch tracking shows "local out of date"

Tags: git

I have pushed all my branches to `origin` from `machine1`. My repo on `machine2` is configured to track all branches. On `machine2` I ran a `git pull` but when I commenced working on branch `feature` I noticed it seemed out of date. Running `git remote show origin` displays "local out of date" for the `feature` branch, but re-running `git pull` displays "Already up-to-date" and `git push` displays "Everything up-to-date".

What is the cause of this (apparent) conflicting information and what can I do to resolve it? Below is the relevant output from git.

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: github:username/repo
  Push  URL: github:username/repo
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    development                 tracked
    feature                     tracked
    master                      tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    development                 merges with remote development
    feature                     merges with remote feature
    master                      merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    development                 pushes to development (up to date)
    feature                     pushes to feature     (local out of date)
    master                      pushes to master      (up to date)

$ git pull
Already up-to-date

$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: What happens whenever you run `git checkout feature; git merge origin/feature`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354284/1227469) seems rather obvious now, but I will not delete the question as you put in the effort to answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` only merges remote into the current branch.

`git pull --help` shows:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.

Read the linked question for further details: [Can “git pull --all” update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)