# how to update all my local git branches with a single script?

Tags: git, shell, git-bash

I wish to use only the git tool and not any other tools to do this. I am looking for a shell script or even it is a inbuilt git sub command which can update all of my local branches by pulling changes from the origin master. So that I can simply run the script or the sub command to get this done.
Please help.

Comment: look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git pull --all` to update all your local branches.